# How can I install tensorflow framework on NAO robot?

Tags: installation, frameworks, tensorflow, nao-robot

I want to install TensorFlow framework to try my MNIST model (a deep neural network to recognize digits) on NAO! I downloaded OpenNAO OS virtual machine in the terminal I tried the commands

$ sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev $ sudo pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.8.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

i got this err! "- bash: apt-get: command not found"

what should I do? Thank you
[TensorFlow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuwoV.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

OpenNao runs on linux but not on ubuntu. It runs on Gentoo, the commands are different.